# console commands py and python is not working Windows

Tags: python, windows, console

Firstly I am a windows 10 user.
I had downloaded python 3.10. As normal to `C:\Program Files\Python310`. Next as in the [tutorial](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows) I tried to use py and python commands(py help, python help, python get-pip.py). But when I write it I see an error:

```
python: can't open file 'c:\\Program Files\\Python310\\help': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

or

```
python: can't open file 'c:\\Program Files\\Python310\\get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

After I reinstall python 3.10. Even delete old exe, and download new from the official site. After uninstalling old Python 3.10 through new exe. And after I have installed Python 3.10 again through new exe in custom mode. Everywhere put a tick. After this again tried to write this command and again commands are not working(similar errors).

Edit. The most strange thing is that `pip` is working, BUT I installed pip with python.exe. So it isn't an exe problem. It is sth other

P.S. I have founded before a few answers for this problem, but or it is only for Mac/Linux or it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not in `C:\Program Files\Python310`. I think it is in `C:\Python310`, or your main drive.

If that way isn't working, I'd try downloading the Python version from the Microsoft store. It automatically sets up the PATH variable for you, so you can just write `python` and it should work.

If it still doesn't work, tell me and I'll delete my useless answer.

Comment: No, it is not `C:\Python310`. It is `C:\Program Files\Python310`(I can see it in file explorer). And PATH variable I also checked when I was downloading python. The most strange thing is that pip is working, BUT I installed pip with python.exe. So it isn't an exe problem. It is sth other